# Why do I get this message from chrome when navigating to https://www.amazon.com?

Tags: google-chrome

> This is probably not the site you are looking for! You attempted to
>   reach www.amazon.com, but instead you actually reached a server
>   identifying itself as *.voxcdn.com. This may be caused by a
>   misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious. An
>   attacker on your network could be trying to get you to visit a fake
>   (and potentially harmful) version of www.amazon.com.

Intermittently, I get a blank page when going to http://www.amazon.com. So I stuck an 's' in the URL, making it https://www.amazon.com and got that message above (with the nice red screen) from Chrome indicating there might be some monkey business going on. After hammering on the URL a bunch of times and pulling it up in Chrome's developer tool to look at the network traffic on it, the url (without the s) started behaving. The url with the s just hangs, but the red screen no longer comes up.

Some specs... I've got a macBook Pro, Snow Leopard, Time Warner cable. I've had enough strange stuff happening over the past couple months (google.com, youtube.com, amazon.com not coming up or loading strange error messages with random reference numbers) that I finally decided to switch to OpenDNS. Still having problems, though.

Comment: What is your router model? Some routers have their own [DNS service/cache](http://superuser.com/a/394731/100787) that can cause issues.

Comment: LinkSys WRT310Nv2, Firmware Version: v2.0.01. I put the OpenDNS settings in there.

Comment: What is the exact hostname displayed in the warning and does this only happen in Chrome? Does it happen on other computers? If this is a legitimate DNS hijacking attempt, then that information may be relevant. I'd also do a reverse lookup on the IP the problem hostnames resolve to. Also log any changes in IP/hostname that those domains resolve to.

Comment: I pasted the exact wording from the error message above. Weird stuff like this happens on all browsers and computers. A couple nights ago I saw odd routing-related errors with battle.net across multiple computers/browsers, so the router or ISP seems likely cause.


I think this article also holds some great clues: http://superuser.com/questions/394436/why-does-my-browser-take-me-to-the-wrong-site 

One thing I've done is remove 192.168.1.1 from my local machine DNS settings. Let's see how that goes.

Comment: Are you currently using your ISP's DNS servers?  Perhaps you can try [Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/) (8.8.4.4 and 8.8.8.8) or [OpenDNS](https://www.opendns.com/opendns-ip-addresses/) (208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220) instead.

Comment: I've used both Google DNS and OpenDNS (currently sticking with OpenDNS). I still had the problem. Yesterday I removed 192.168.1.1 from my local machine's DNS settings and I'm going to report back in a week to hopefully confirm that I no longer have problems. So far so good.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your hosts file has been hijacked?
Post the contents of your host file by opening it in a txt editor and copy/pasting it here.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system

Comment: Do Macs have a Hosts file? (I'm a Windows guy, I am just curious.) .. and after reading the Wiki, I see that they do. Neat.

Comment: In addition to having an `/etc/hosts` file, OS X also keeps hosts in Directory Service: see `dscl . -list /Local/Defaults/Hosts IPAddress`.

Comment: I need to get my hands on a Mac Book..

Comment: Hosts file is clean. Thanks for the suggestion. This problem has affected all machines on the network.