# Why can't I access a particular website even though the server appears to be available

Tags: windows-7, internet, internet-connection

I can't access http://www.lynda.com/ with any of my browsers on my home network.

By checking http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/, I can see that the server is up and I can access it via a proxy like TOR.

This screen appears immediately after I type the page in

[image]

It doesn't even try to load the page, it seems.  Though when I `ping` the server I get this:

[image]

I tried to do `ipconfig /flushdns`. But it didn't help either.

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What DNS addresses are you using? If you have a Linksys router, this question may be helpful: http://superuser.com/a/394731/100787

Comment: Are you trying to access from a country that censors the internet? Are you behind a badly-configured corporate firewall that silently drops connections instead of hijacking and displaying a "you're not allowed" message?

Comment: Instead of `ping` which just gives a pass/fail, try using `tracert` to see where the connection is getting lost.

Comment: @Wooble I'm at home in Norway (uncencored). The webpage has worked before. Though this page works: http://screencast.com/t/N4hxBu5m 

So I'm not behind any badly-configured corporate firewall.

Comment: @iglvzx I've tried my ISP's DNS servers and Google's (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4) None worked...

Comment: @embedded.kyle http://screencast.com/t/MNVk3z3t

Comment: Since the general failure is immediate, it is defiantly a problem with your PC. Do you have any security apps installed like Malwarebytes? Other solutions I've seen around involve changing various settings on the NIC. http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/426862, http://www.thewinforums.com/threads/14729-Resolved-Ping-Tracert-gives-quot-general-failure-quot-message.../page2?s=acdab9cce02f742e6cc8cd4d25cabea6

Comment: I noticed that the same happens to multiple sites, even a norwegian weather forecast site!

Comment: @embedded.kyle I have Microsoft Forefront Protection, though it hasn't blocked it before..

Comment: @embedded.kyle I got it working. You were right! It was a program blocking it... Please post it as an answer to be accepted! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `ping` which just gives a pass/fail, try using `tracert` to see where the connection is getting lost.

If both `ping` and `tracert` respond immediately with a `General failure.`, it is defiantly a problem with your PC. Do you have any security apps installed like Malwarebytes? Other solutions I've seen around involve changing various settings on the NIC.

http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/426862

http://www.thewinforums.com/threads/14729-Resolved-Ping-Tracert-gives-quot-general-failure-quot-message.../page2?s=acdab9cce02f742e6cc8cd4d25cabea6